# Implementing Chrome-like Asynchronous 'fetch' Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to implement a Chrome like `fetch` function in Node.js using Promises. Here's what I have achieved so far:

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: 'eternagame.wikia.com',
  path: '/wiki/EteRNA_Dictionary'
};

const fetchHtml = options => new Promise(

(resolve, reject) =>

    http.get(options, function (http_res) {
        var data = "";
        http_res.on("data", buffer => data += buffer);

        http_res.on("end", function () {
            console.log("fetch complete");
            resolve(data);
        });
    })
)


fetchHtml(options).then(console.log("fetch actually complete"));
```

The problem is that for some weird reason, "fetch actually complete" is printed first and then "fetch complete" is printed. This should be the other way round, since "fetch actually complete" is wrapped in the `then` routine of the Promise.

Why is this so? I'm calling the `resolve` in `http_res.on("end",...` block. Isn't the `then` routine started when the promise has resolved?

Comment: Because you're executing the expression, not passing it as a callback. (Also, [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) already exists...)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the the console.log("fetch actually complete") inside a function? Haven't tested it since my Node isn't cooperating, but I have a hunch that as written, that log gets executed immediately, since `then()` expects a function and console.log doesn't return a function.

Comment: @Shilly, thank you so much. Changing it to () => console.log solved it!

Comment: @Cosmonavt This is a simple problem that has come up thousands of times on this site! `console.log('...')` is run immediately, because it's an expression. `function(){console.log('...');}` or `()=>console.log('...')` create function objects, which are run at the appropriate time. It's the same as `setTimeout(console.log('now'), 10000);`: the  string will be logged immediately, not after ten seconds.

Comment: Oh, and I realise this is a learning exercise. But don't make it production code!

Comment: @lonesomeday, Sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the console.log statement in the resolve section:

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: 'eternagame.wikia.com',
  path: '/wiki/EteRNA_Dictionary'
};

const fetchHtml = options => new Promise(

(resolve, reject) =>
    http.get(options, function (http_res) {
        var data = "";
        http_res.on("data", buffer => data += buffer);

        http_res.on("end", function () {
            console.log("fetch complete");
            resolve(data);
        });
    })
)


fetchHtml(options).then(
    data => {
        // data is available here
        console.log("fetch actually complete")
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Alternatively, you can use [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch), a module that will give you exactly what you're trying to implement.

---

To handle actual error status codes and other unwanted status codes, you can use the reject function available to your promise as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yqycahpb/).

Comment: Yes I did figure it out. One more thing: I am using the `resolve` function in the Promise but not the `error` function. Will `console.error` EVER be executed? If no, then any change I can make to the Promise so it may be executed?

Comment: It won't trigger straight away, you need to reject both errors and unwanted status codes. You can do something like so: https://jsfiddle.net/yqycahpb/

Comment: That was really helpful :) Thank you so much! Might as well edit your answer and paste them there. I've already accepted it and upvoted it.

Comment: Added a note and the JSFiddle link to the answer.